# Is it possible to manage all tags (add, edit and delete) with acts-as-taggable-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, acts-as-taggable-on

I use the acts-as-taggable-on gem with only one (default) tag list. I wonder whether it is possible to create a form to manage tags with the following features. (Went through all answers and only found solutions for Activeadmin.)

1. I managed to get a list of all tags (across associated models) using ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all.
2. I want to be able to edit each tag name (text input field).
3. I want to be able to delete (destroy) a tag (checkbox).
4. Lastly I want to be able to add a tag to the list as we use only categories user can add to different models. (maybe with [find_or_create_with_like_by_name](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/ActsAsTaggableOn/Tag#find_or_create_all_with_like_by_name-class_method))

How would I construct the two forms 1-3 and 4? Is that at all possible with acts_as_taggable? Thanks for any hint in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself.

### View

#### Add tags

```
form_tag "/tags" do
  text_field_tag :name
  submit_tag "Add tag"
```

#### Update and delete tags

```
@tags.each do |tag|
  text_field_tag "tags[#{tag.id}]name", tag.name, class: 'name'
  <button class="update-tag radius small">Save</button>
  <button class="delete-tag radius small">Delete</button>


$(function(){
  $(".delete-tag").on("click", function(){
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    $.post("/tags/" + row.data("id"), {_method: "DELETE"}, function(){
      row.remove();
    })
  })

  $(".update-tag").on("click", function(){
    var row = $(this).closest("tr");
    $.post("/tags/" + row.data("id"), {_method: "PUT", name: row.find('.name').val()})
  })
})
```

### Controller

```
class TagsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    name = params[:name]
    ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.create(name: name)
    redirect_to :back
  end

  def destroy
    tag = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find(params[:id])
    tag.destroy
    render json: {success: true}
  end

  def update
    tag = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find(params[:id])
    tag.update_attributes(name: params[:name])
    render json: {success: true}
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You edit and add tags to the object. So if you have a Photos model you would do.. /photos/1/edit to edit the photo and the tags... the same way you added them. There is a column on your Photo model for this purpose. Question 4 I don't understand... You want to give them a list of tags to choose from?, if so this is easy too use collection select.

If you search you will find loads of form examples.